# What to use as continuous power supplier with Sony a7II?

Tags: dslr, battery, camera, power-supply, power

I try to figure out how to provide my camera with enough power during video shootings and I have purchased a dummy battery with USB-C power adapter to connect it to power bank, but when I connected it to my camera nothing happened.

I think its because of the output voltage difference:

Powerbank USB-C has 5V;

[image]

PD Adapter needs 9V-20V;

[image]

I have also tried to search for a power bank with 9V output but couldn't find anything.

If someone uses such adapters in real life, how do you power it? What power bank/power supplier should I consider to buy in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB-C has two power modes:

- 5V for peripherals and phones
- Up 20V or so when used as a power source for laptops (the recent generation no longer has a dedicated power socket). The actual voltage appears to be negotiated between the power source and the device.

The small & lightweight power banks deliver 5V because they are meant for smartphones. There is however a new type of power banks that aims at laptops and are likely what you are looking for since they deliver higher voltages. On Amazon they are often advertized as working with MacBooks (since Apple was the first to use this USB-C capability for its laptops). Not in the same capacity, size, price,  and weight area, though. See [this](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/best-usb-c-battery-packs-and-power-banks/) for a few examples.

Comment: hey @xenoid thanks for your comment! It helped me a lot to decide what powerbank I need to look for. In my case, my camera started to work when I purchased a powerbank that is compatible to work with laptops and has USB-Type C Output range 5V 3A/ 9V 3A/ 12V 3A/ 15V 3A/ 20V 2A. My first powerbank had only 5V 3A Type C Output and it was obviously not enough to power a camera.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is [car power starter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T9S3Q5N) which usually provide 12 volts output.

Also big power banks may provide 12V DC output. Here is [one example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08P7H741K)

N.B. No affiliation with manufactures and sellers.

Because most of those products are based on Li-ion and transport via airplane delivery is questionable will be wise to buy from Local shops (for example for Germany amazon.de or Saturn)

Comment: This will not work over USB.  The OP's dummy battery requires a power supply which supports USB Power Delivery - not just an non-negotiated 12 volts.  Putting 12 volts on a USB line is quite likely to fry something

Comment: @maples, as you can see in the question there is device between power source and the dummy battery which will provide the correct voltage.